# initialization a function once in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have multiple google maps in one web page like below

```
<div class="map_wrapper">
    <div class="map_heading"><h2>Map1</h2><a href="#" class="map_link">Map Show</a></div>
    <div class="map_canvas">map parameters goes here</div>
</div>
<div class="map_wrapper">
    <div class="map_heading"><h2>Map1</h2><a href="#" class="map_link">Map Show</a></div>
    <div class="map_canvas">map parameters goes here</div>
</div>
<div class="map_wrapper">
    <div class="map_heading"><h2>Map1</h2><a href="#" class="map_link">Map Show</a></div>
    <div class="map_canvas">map parameters goes here</div>
</div>
```

i am using google maps v3, and the map function works well, i have function `maps_init();`

so i use jquery

in this way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".map_link").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().children(".map_canvas").slideToggle(100);
        var map = $(this).parent().parent().children(".map_canvas");
        maps_init(map);
    });
});
```

how can i make this work when i click the link then it call the function otherwise never call again that function, because user can click the `"map_link"` to see multiple times and every time it initializes the function, so i need the reference in every div `"map_wrapper"` for it's own which will check. if not initialized then it will initialize otherwise not, i can not use in `map_init()` function in `document.ready()` because it initializes all the maps and maps does not looks correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: why not unbind the click event on the map_link after the first click?

Comment: sorry can you explain please

Comment: i misunderstood your question, i thought you were trying to make the map_init function only be called once per page, but it looks like you're trying to have it initialized once per div. sorry about that

Comment: yes it is once per div.Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a class to keep track of the initialized maps:

```
$(".map_link").click(function(){
        if(!($(this).hasClass('initialized')) {
            $(this).parent().parent().children(".map_canvas").slideToggle(100);
            var map = $(this).parent().parent().children(".map_canvas");
            maps_init(map);
            $(this).addClass('initialized');
        }
    });
});
```

Might not be the cleanest solution but I guess it's simple and fast

OR

you could use jQuery's "one" method, which will fire only once:

http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/WQPjn/

```
$('a').one('click', function(e) {
    alert('map initialized');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

in your case:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".map_link").one('click',function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().children(".map_canvas").slideToggle(100);
        var map = $(this).parent().parent().children(".map_canvas");
        maps_init(map);
    });
});
```